# DataGridView no muestra datos

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview, sql-server-2019, visual-studio-2022

Tengo un DataGridView en un Form de Windows que no muestra datos.
El **DataGridView** tiene en su propiedad DataSource un objeto BindingSource, este **BindingSource** a su vez tiene en su propiedad DataSource una lista de objetos.
Ejecuté el programa paso a paso y todo parece estar bien, los datos van correctamente hasta la propiedad DataSource del DataGridView pero no me muestra ningún dato en el Form.
A continuación les mostrare el código para que puedan entenderlo mejor.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string cadenaConexionSQL = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True";
        private IEnumerable<Equipo> listaEquipos;
        private BindingSource sourceEquipos;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cargarObjetos();
        }
        private void cargarObjetos()
        {
            sourceEquipos = new BindingSource();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sourceEquipos;
            listaEquipos = GetAll();
            sourceEquipos.DataSource = listaEquipos;
        }
        private List<Equipo> GetAll()
        {
            var listaEquipos = new List<Equipo>();
            using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(this.cadenaConexionSQL))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                conexion.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conexion;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM equipos ORDER BY id DESC";
                using (var lector = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (lector.Read())
                    {
                        var equipo = new Equipo();
                        equipo.setId((int)lector[0]);
                        equipo.setNombre(lector[1].ToString());
                        equipo.setColor(lector[2].ToString());
                        listaEquipos.Add(equipo);
                    }
                }
            }
            return listaEquipos;
        }
    }
    public class Equipo
    {
        private int id;
        private string nombre;
        private string color;
        public Equipo()
        {
            id = 0; nombre = ""; color = "";
        }
        public int getId() { return id; }
        public string getNombre() { return nombre; }
        public string getColor() { return color; }
        public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
        public void setNombre(string nombre) { this.nombre = nombre; }
        public void setColor(string color) { this.color = color; }
    }
```

Intenté poner la lista directamente en la propiedad DataSource del DataGridView y no se muestran resultados.
En el diseño añadí las columnas manualmente (3 columnas) y puse en la propiedad **DataPropertyName** de cada columna el nombre del campo de la tabla de la base de datos, con esto se generararon filas en el DataGridView. El **número de filas** que generó el DataGridView corresponden con el **número de registros** que existen en la tabla de la base de datos, el problema es que los campos se muestran **vacíos o en blanco**, tambien revisé el color del texto pero esta todo correcto.
Si pueden encontrar el error o si tienen una mejor forma de realizar lo anterior me ayudarían mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasa que tu clase `Equipo` tiene demasiado tufo a JAVA. En C# se denominan `Property` (propiedades) a las variables que tienen `{get;set;}` y son las propiedades las que son "bindeables" en los componentes. Por ejemplo tú dices que ocupaste `Data**Property**Name` pero en tu clase tienes cero propiedades.

Tu clase debería ser así:

```
public class Equipo
{
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string nombre {get; set;}
        public string color {get; set;}
        public Equipo()
        {
            id = 0; nombre = ""; color = "";
        }
}
```

Que como verás es incluso más corto

Comment: Es justo eso!!!! Gracias Yussef por la respuesta, pregunté a varias personas y no pudieron ayudarme, me hizo gracia lo de TUFO A JAVA por que efectivamente llevo dos años programando en solo java. Queda demás decir que esta es la respuesta correcta GRACIAS GRACIAS.